# QUrl, get a string url with location that contains "//"

Tags: qurl

I create a URL using `QUrl`.

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_btnExecute_clicked()
{
    QUrl url;
    url.setScheme("https");
    url.setPath("myPath");

    QUrlQuery query;

    query.addQueryItem("myQuery", "query1");

    url.setQuery(query);
    const auto debug = url.toString(QUrl::FullyEncoded);
}
```

The string of the URL is *"http:myPath"* but I need *"http://myPath"*

I've tried `toString()`, `toDisplayString()` with different `FormattingOptions` but with no luck.